# File pathing leading to errors

Tags: java, filepath

I'm working on a new program that opens different files. The thing is when I change the computer and the files need to be opened they don't because the computer can't find those files. Is there a way to make the files reachable even on another computer? I mean the files are in a folder inside the project but the path changes when you open it on a new computer.

```
 File myFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Info12\\src\\info12\\Dokumente\\Aufgaben\\Bubblesort.docx");
```

Comment: To clarify, you are referring to files that are part of your project, not files that just randomly happen to be there?

Comment: Can you put the files on the classpath and read them from there? Alternatively have the users define a $home variable from which your paths will be computed

Comment: I am referring to files that are part of my project, they are in folders created directly in Netbeans in which I put my files in.

Answer (score 0):

In a Maven Project, all yours files are in `src/main/resources` so:

src/main/resources/info12/Dokumente/Aufgaben/Bubblesort.docx

Your java code is:

```
File myFile = new File("src\\main\\resources\\info12\\Dokumente\\Aufgaben\\Bubblesort.docx")
```

and more smart:

```
File myFile = new File("src" + File.separator + "main" + File.separator + "resources" + File.separator + "info12" + File.separator + "Dokumente" + File.separator + "Aufgaben" + File.separator + "Bubblesort.docx")
```